# Seeking English term for relationship between two members of extended family?

Tags: kinship-terminology

Here at the Genealogy and Family History Stack Exchange we see many questions about relationship mapping which is also known as:

- relationship calculation
- kinship terminology
- etc

If you are just trying to understand how to calculate "cousins and removes" then [How to determine relationship with a cousin?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/218/how-to-determine-relationship-with-a-cousin) provides an excellent guide.

However, if you are seeking an English term for a more complicated relationship between two members of an extended family, rather than asking a question like:

- [What is my step-father's second wife's child to me?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/9538/what-is-my-step-fathers-second-wifes-child-to-me)
- [What is relationship of widower to late wife's family (i.e. in-laws)?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/9253/what-is-relationship-of-widower-to-late-wifes-family-i-e-in-laws)
- [What would a step-grandmother's(?) brother be called?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/5273/what-would-a-step-grandmothers-brother-be-called)
- [What is sibling of son-in-law or daughter-in-law called?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/6809/what-is-sibling-of-son-in-law-or-daughter-in-law-called)

site users are encouraged to first review the answers below.

---

Note: This Q&A arises from [On- and off-topic questions: kinship terms / relationship questions](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1957/on-and-off-topic-questions-kinship-terms) and is set to [Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) to help make it canonical.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The determination of relationship terms -- what is X called -- is a task best suited to linguists and anthropologists, who ask informants to describe what is happening in their own culture.  Software exists to help in collecting these terms, and matching them against known libraries of kinship terms in other cultures -- one such tool is SIL's [SILKin](http://www.sil.org/resources/software_fonts/silkin).

It is far more likely that hobbyist family historians and genealogists will be performing the opposite task -- finding a relationship term in a document and having to puzzle out what relationship was meant.  In that case, it is important to remember that the meaning of kinship terms -- like the meaning of all words -- changes over time, and also varies  depending on geographical location.

Calling someone "uncle" or "aunt" in the southern United States might not indicate a person is a blood relative -- it could be a courtesy title for a trusted family friend, used by a younger person to address an elder.  The word "uncle" had a different meaning in colonial America -- for references see the links in my answer to the question [Familial Terminology in Colonial America](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/5437/familial-terminology-in-colonial-america/5440#5440).

If you are a native speaker of English, and you have to ask someone else what the English relationship term for a particular relationship is, the answer may be that there is no special term.  As AdrianB38 says in his comment on the question, your father's step-father is your father's step-father.  There may not be any specialized term for the relationship, and even if such a term did exist, you might not wish to use it.

Someone who is close to his father's step-father may simply say "my grandfather", but someone else who doesn't want to be inclusive may say "my grandmother's second husband" or "that person my father's mother married" (or some variant which is even less polite). In a blended family, insisting on being ultra-precise about one's relationship to a person in your family (always calling someone your "half-sister" instead of "my sister", or saying "my stepbrother's son" instead of simply saying "my nephew") might be considered dismissive and rude.

For the standard "cousin / removed" terminology which is commonly found in genealogy, there are many charts and relationship calculators available like the one on Steve Morse's One-Step Web pages referred to in the other answer.  The principle is to find the common ancestor between you and your relative, then work your way downward to determine how many levels are involved.  The "removed" reference means that you and your cousin are on different levels, that is, not of the same number of generations away from the common ancestor.

The answer to the question, "Are we related -- and if so, what is the relationship called?" might differ greatly between the social sphere and the legal one.  If a legal matter of inheritance is involved, it is best to consult a lawyer; for the  precise term for a complicated relationship, consult a professional genealogist.  For one professional's perspective, see the article by Elizabeth Shown Mills linked to below.

Further reading:

- ["That Particular Relative"](http://www.legalgenealogist.com/2015/02/23/that-particular-relative/) by Judy G. Russell, published Feb 23, 2015 on her blog *The Legal Genealogist*, where she talks about **shirt-tail relatives**.
- [A Relationship Chart by Betty Eichhorn](https://web.archive.org/web/20160408042159/http://blog.eogn.com/2015/01/20/a-relationship-chart-by-betty-eichhorn/) by Dick Eastman, published January 20, 2015 on Eastman's Online Genealogy Newsletter -- article contains link to [downloadable PDF](https://web.archive.org/web/20160408042159/http://eogn.com/images/newsletter/2015/Relationship_Chart.pdf)
- [Is There Any Such Thing as a Half-Cousin?](https://web.archive.org/web/20160409084745/https://blog.eogn.com/2015/01/21/is-there-any-such-thing-as-a-half-cousin/) by Dick Eastman, published January 21, 2015 on Eastman's Online Genealogy Newsletter
- [“The Kinship Maze: Navigating It with Professional Precision.”](http://historicpathways.com/download/navkinmaze.pdf), originally published in Association of Professional Genealogists Quarterly 20 (June 2005): 61–70. Digital image. Elizabeth Shown Mills, Historic Pathways. http://www.HistoricPathways.com : [PDF available from the author].
- [Kinship terminology: How we refer to our family relationships](https://web.archive.org/web/20131215073939/https://blog.findmypast.com/2013/kinship-terminology-how-we-refer-to-our-family-relationships/) from the Find My Past blog.

Answer (score 8):

As can be seen from many earlier Q&As here, the [Relationship Calculator of Stephen P. Morse](http://www.stevemorse.org/relation/calculator.html), is an easy to use tool for this purpose and has either been applied to, or could be applied to, these questions:

- [What would a step-grandmother's(?) brother be called?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/5273/what-would-a-step-grandmothers-brother-be-called/5274#5274)
- [Step-father of Step-father](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3033/step-father-of-step-father)
- [What is sibling of son-in-law or daughter-in-law called?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/6809/what-is-sibling-of-son-in-law-or-daughter-in-law-called/6810#6810)
- [Determining name for family relationship that involves a step daughter?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/5284/determining-name-for-family-relationship-that-involves-a-step-daughter)
- [Is there a resource for easily determining relationships between two relatives?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/5293/is-there-a-resource-for-easily-determining-relationships-between-two-relatives)
- [With generations of multiple marriages and step children, how is this family relationship described?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/1510/with-generations-of-multiple-marriages-and-step-children-how-is-this-family-rel)
- [What is the relationship name of my wife's brother-in-law to me?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/12028)

Conversely, the tool and the question depend on two assumptions, viz:

- That there *is* a name for the relationship being asked about;
- That the name of the relationship is useful because it defines a *specific* relationship and *not* several others;

It can be argued that (for instance) the step-father of your father is just called "the step-father of your father". So far as I can see, there *isn't* a name (in *English* - other languages may differ) for this relationship - it can only be *described*.

The Stephen P Morse Relationship Calculator gives the same term ["step grandfather"] for "father of my step-father" [entered as "mother's husband's father"] as for "step-father of my father" [entered as "father's mother's husband"]. Arguably this means the term is often ambiguous. To avoid lack of clarity, we should encourage people to *describe* the relationship, and not use a misleading name.

Another example is that your wife's brother-in-law is just called "your wife's brother-in-law".

A FindMypast blog which may be of interest is [Kinship Terminology Explained (or How to Know What to Call Distant Relatives)](http://rbl.ms/1PL7JfI).