# Relationship terminology after death of a relative

Tags: kinship-terminology

Please can someone tell me, when a married woman dies, would her widower still be called the son in law of his late wife's parents?  If so, would that title continue to apply if he remarried? He might then have a new mother and father in law, so could he be son in law to both sets of parents?

Comment: Hi Gina & welcome. This question has come up before: [What is relationship of widower to late wife's family (i.e. in-laws)?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/9253/) No worries, I will close this question as a duplicate of the other. If you have any additional questions not answered by the above duplicate, feel free to post it separately.

Comment: Thank you Harry, I will check that out.  Apologies for the duplication.

Comment: It's no problem, Gina. Just when duplicates come up we try to flag them as such so that all the answers are in one place.