# What is the relationship name of the brother of my 1st Cousin's Spouse to me?

Tags: united-kingdom, kinship-terminology, italy

In Italy I grew up calling many people simply cousins or uncles and I have called my 1st Cousin's Spouse's brother ([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUDag.jpg)) a cousin all along. I am just curious to know whether according to normal family relationship conventions I can even call him a cousin of sorts. Can you please shed some light on what my relationship to him would be called?

[image: My relationship to said relative]

Comment: Please see [Seeking English term for relationship between two members of extended family?](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/6818/). Questions of this kind are usually closed as duplicates because the answer is invariably: there is no specific name for this relationship. You could call him your cousin's brother-in-law. Of course he's not a cousin by blood, but if you want to call him a cousin that's fine.

Comment: The cousin's brother in-law was my best guess. Its just these didn't seem covered in any direct manner.

Comment: The colloquial English expression for someone distantly related or related only by marriage is "shirt-tail relative".  It's perfectly okay to call him a cousin in everyday conversation.  If you are doing DNA or formal genealogy, then you can specify just as you have done in the question. See http://www.legalgenealogist.com/2015/02/23/that-particular-relative/ or http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-shi5.htm