# First cousins relative to the cousin

Tags: kinship-terminology

Can someone please help. I'm wondering that if there are two people A and B, such that A' s grandparent is B's great grandparent.  Is it the case that B is A's first cousin once removed and A is B's second cousin once removed. Or is it just that they are both first cousins once removed?

Comment: https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/6818/seeking-english-term-for-relationship-between-two-members-of-extended-family should help you work it out.

Comment: With respect, the linked answers, so far as I can see, do NOT acknowledge that both the above options have been used by various people. Some are adamant that the relationship name is the same in both directions. Others are adamant that it isn't.