# Situation of step siblings and not half siblings; Am I correct?

Tags: kinship-terminology

From a fiction story

At the age of 40, Mr. Scottsdale, an Agricultural Manager, divorced his wife of 39 years old. She got the custody of their daughter. At fault, he surrendered to her their matrimonial house, one quarter of all agricultural real estate parcels and four thousand dollars of alimonies a month. He lived with enough resources. He remarried and had a son who married at 28 years old. They had a son, Patrick, who now is 25 years old and whose grandparents died.

His ex-wife, Mrs. Scottsdale-Rigby, then 39 years old never remarried is now 85 years old. But their daughter married at 25 years old; the couple had two daughters Priscilla now 19 and Nadine 21. The spouses and daughters lived ever since in Grandma’s inherited house.

Priscilla, Nadine, and Patrick are step siblings.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why this has been put on hold. The link from "genealogy" in the help centre takes you to the Meta post with this definition: "Genealogy is the study of families in genetic and historical context. Within that framework, it is the study of the people who compose a family _**and the relationships among them**_". (my emphasis). The question may be inspired from a work of fiction, but it is still about "genealogy".

Comment: @sempaiscuba I only saw this one briefly last night and decided not to close vote until I could take a longer look, but I certainly considered doing so because I think the actual question being asked could be much clearer.  The story (chit chat) woven around the question hides that it seems to simply want to know what the English term is for the relationship between Priscilla/Nadine and Patrick.  That question would be a duplicate of https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/6818.

Comment: @PolyGeo That's fine. It was just the idea that a question about family relationships was "off-topic" that didn't make sense to me. :)

Comment: @sempaiscuba I think the community is generally much more receptive to questions about understanding our users' own genealogy and family history rather than on hypothetical/fictitious scenarios.  I suspect it was "[You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)" that may have led to it being placed on hold as off-topic.  Whether it should have been may be a question suitable for [meta.genealogy.se].

Answer (score 1):

Mr Scotsdale's son and daughter are half-siblings - they share one blood-parent (their father).

His grandchildren Priscilla and Nadine are the [half-cousins](http://www.cousinsplus.com/families/CousinsPlus/trees/cousinship-defined.htm) of Patrick, since they they share only one common grandparent.

Comment: Sorting things the right way as you did allow others to get in touch with a reality no one should ignore. Thanks for the tip. The circumstances of my example in my recent short-story affects generations combined as parenting is probably the most difficult and endearing duty one faces in one life.

Comment: The term step-sibling, however, escaped its definition versus half- cousins. It's though clear that half-cousins share half of the DNA, half the blood.

Answer (score 1):

Siblings share parents.
Half-siblings share one parent.

Patrick's parents are the son and his wife.
Priscilla and Nadine's parents are the daughter and her husband.
Therefore they are not siblings - half, step or otherwise.

They are second cousins through their shared grandparent.